# Elastic Multimatch string with dash (or other symbol)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, fuzzy-search

I am trying to match dashes (and other symbols) in my elastic query.

It is fuzzysearch on all the fields using default whitespace analyzer.

My query:

```
function_score: {
        query: {
            multi_match: {
                query: string
                analyzer: "whitespace",
                fuzziness: 1
            }
        }
    }
```

However this has unexpected results with dash characters. E.x. Central-Park doesnt work with this. Or

Dashes only work well when I use a phrase match and strip out the double quotes. But there is no fuzziness.

Does anyone know how I can get the fuzzysearch normally with dashes please?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "place": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "place": "Cwntral-Park"
}
{
  "place": "Central-Park"
}
{
  "place": "Central-Area"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "place": {
            "query": "Central-Park",
            "fuzziness": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65605120",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "place": "Central-Park"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65605120",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.8990934,
        "_source": {
          "place": "Cwntral-Park"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Allen H. did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @Allen H. if my answer helped you resolve your issue, can you please accept and upvote the answer as well 

Comment: @@Allen H. can you please reply back to my previous comments ?